# Changing label.text after button click

Tags: swift, xcode

I wish to make a mathematical quiz app. When the program loads up the label is set to the first question which is created randomly and doesn't use an array to hold the questions.

The correct answer and "fake answers" are assigned to 4 buttons correctly and what i'm looking to do now is when one of the buttons is clicked, i want to check if the buttons current title is the same as the correct answer and then move on and generate the new question and answers.

This is the code i wrote which i thought would do what i wish, however it doesn't.

```
 @IBAction func button1Press(_ sender: Any) {
    if button1.currentTitle == ("\(answer)")
    {
        rightAnswerCount = rightAnswerCount + 1
        generateQuestion()
        generateAnswer()
        displayButtonValues()
    }
    else {
        wrongAnswerCount = wrongAnswerCount + 1
        generateQuestion()
        generateAnswer()
        displayButtonValues()
    }
}
```

What are the improvements i can make on this code to make it work?

Thanks!

---

*Added from OP's comment*

To assign the buttons titles, i do this;

```
if buttonNo == 4 { 
    button4.setTitle("(answer)", for: .normal) 
} else { 
    button4.setTitle("(answer + 5)", for: .normal)
```

### }

The other functions;

```
func generateQuestion(){
    switch symbolNo {
    case 1:
        operatorSymbol = "+"
        self.lbl.text = "\(firstNo) + \(secondNo) = ?"
        question = "\(firstNo) + \(secondNo) = ?"
    case 2 :
        operatorSymbol = "-"
        self.lbl.text = "\(firstNo) - \(secondNo) = ?"
        question = "\(firstNo) - \(secondNo) = ?"
    case 3 :
        operatorSymbol = "/"
        self.lbl.text = "\(firstNo) / \(secondNo) = ?"
        question = "\(firstNo) / \(secondNo) = ?"
    case 4 :
        operatorSymbol = "x"
        self.lbl.text = "\(firstNo) x \(secondNo) = ?"
        question = "\(firstNo) x \(secondNo) = ?"

    default:
        self.lbl.text = ""
    }
}

func generateAnswer(){
    switch symbolNo {
    case 1:
        answer = firstNo + secondNo
    case 2:
        answer = firstNo - secondNo
    case 3:
        answer = firstNo / secondNo
    case 4:
        answer = firstNo * secondNo
    default:
        answer = 0
    }
}

func displayButtonValues(){
    if buttonNo == 1 {
        button1.setTitle("\(answer)", for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        button1.setTitle("\(answer - 4)", for: .normal)
        }
    if buttonNo == 2 {
        button2.setTitle("\(answer)", for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        button2.setTitle("\(answer - 2)", for: .normal)
        }
    if buttonNo == 3 {
        button3.setTitle("\(answer)", for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        button3.setTitle("\(answer + 3)", for: .normal)
        }
    if buttonNo == 4 {
        button4.setTitle("\(answer)", for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        button4.setTitle("\(answer + 5)", for: .normal)
        }

    }
```

I also have these 3 functions in here so that when the app loads for the first time, these functions are immediately executed;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    generateQuestion()
    generateAnswer()
    displayButtonValues()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

variables

```
let firstNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(10)+1)
let secondNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(10)+1)
let symbolNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(4)+1)
let buttonNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(4)+1)
var operatorSymbol = ""
var answer = Int()
var question = ""
var rightAnswerCount = 0
var wrongAnswerCount = 0
```

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Not compiling? Crashing? Not working as expected?

Comment: The code isn't working as expected, the functions that are called when the button is pressed are not called and I'm unsure why.. It compiles perfectly and does not crash.

Comment: How do you assign the titles on your buttons?

Comment: To assign the buttons titles, i do this;

" if buttonNo == 4 {
            button4.setTitle("\(answer)", for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            button4.setTitle("\(answer + 5)", for: .normal)
            } "

Comment: At the start of `func button1Press`, add a couple of `print`s - `print(button1.currentTitle)` and `print("\(answer)")` just to check what you're comparing

Comment: I can give a tip. Make us of the sender parameter. This way, all button presses can be subscribed to this 1 function. (ie. sender.currentTitle == ...)  There's no use having 4 of the same functions for 4 of the buttons that do the same thing. You can also make (_ sender: Any) into (_ sender: UIButton)

Comment: @dstaton I think you want to generate new random values each time you make a new question. Your randomized variables are constants, and never changed. Change your random variables to var and before calling your generate functions, assign a new random value to these variables. This explains why it works the first time, and you don't see the changes afterward.

Comment: @Shen i changed the "let" to "var" and I made a new func which randomises all of these variables and its working correctly!

Comment: @dstaton Good to hear. I've provided an answer to help anyone who comes across this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should compare you buttons this way:

```
if button1.titleLabel?.text==answer{
    print("good answer")
    rightAnswerCount += 1
}else{
    print("bad answer")
    wrongAnswerCount += 1
}
generateQuestion()
generateAnswer()
displayButtonValues()
```

Comment: `currentTitle` should work fine and (as a get-only property) is probably the correct one to use.

Comment: This would only show if the answer was correct or incorrect once the button is clicked, i want the next question to be generated and assigned to the label and then the answers generated and be assigned to the buttons which is done by using those functioned listed in my code above, this is why I'm so confused as it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I don't understand what is not working or what is your question.

Comment: Looking at the code that i showed originally, When the button is pressed, if the button.currentTitle == answer then the functions should be called.

if the button.currentTitle is not equal to answer, the functions should still be called to generate a new question, answer and then display the button values.

Comment: Print something in both case (good or wrong answer) to see if the right action is fired.

Comment: I have done what you have said and the correct button click prints good answer and the incorrect button click prints bad answer, however the functions after the prints are not being called and I'm not sure why

Comment: @dstaton Edit your question with the code of the other functions. There has to be a reason.

Comment: Did you put some breakpoints in your code? I don't see why the function should not be called. Print something also in these functions to see if it enters in it.

Comment: Surely printing something in these other functions wouldn't matter as i know they work as the generateQuestion function does change the label to a question, The generate answer function does work as i can compare the printing of the good and bad answer in the NSLog and the displayButtonValues does work as the buttons have their titles set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
let firstNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(10)+1)
let secondNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(10)+1)
let symbolNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(4)+1)
let buttonNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(4)+1)
```

These constants need to be changed to `var` and assigned a new value before each question is generated. This explains why it works the first time, but no changes are seen afterward.